# Testing presence of multiple files within loop

Tags: bash, if-statement, reduction, command-line-arguments

Assume a *bash* script to which four commandline arguments are passed. Each of these arguments represents a path to, and a name of, an input file (i.e., `INF1`, `INF2`, `INF3`, `INF4`). I would like to evaluate for each of these four input files, if it exists and - if a file does not exist as specified - exit the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Assigning commandline arguments
INF1=$1
INF2=$2
INF3=$3
INF4=$4

# Check if input files exist
if [ ! -f $1 ]; then
    echo -ne " ERROR | File not found: $1\n"
    exit 1
fi
if [ ! -f $2 ]; then
    echo -ne " ERROR | File not found: $2\n"
    exit 1
fi
if [ ! -f $3 ]; then
    echo -ne " ERROR | File not found: $3\n"
    exit 1
fi
if [ ! -f $4 ]; then
    echo -ne " ERROR | File not found: $4\n"
    exit 1
fi
```

I would think that having four individual if-statements here is unnecessary, and that the same functionality can be achieved with a single if-statement, wrapped into a loop. How can I reduce the code in this aspect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in a script

```
#!/bin/bash

for v; do
if [ ! -f "$v" ]; then
    echo "ERROR | File not found: $v"
    exit 1
fi
done
```

Comment: You can even skip the `in "$@"` part, because that's the default if you don't have an `in` clause.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare an array and assing the variables and loop through it.

```
ARRAY=()
ARRAY+=$1
ARRAY+=$2 ..
```

and

```
for i in "${arrayName[@]}"
do
   : 
   # do whatever on $i
done
```